# Where could I learn basic math terminology?

Tags: terminology, education

I am an english learner and I would like to learn the etymology of Mathematics. I would like to know the most common phrases in Algebra, and Geometry as well. I want to know at a level of 
UK's A+. (If I am right there is something like that in secondary schools)

Comment: I would like to know about some websites or books that are available for free on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great place to learn terminology is the Encyclopedia of Mathematics https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org. Additionally, wikipedia is also useful.

Comment: It's quite good, but I would find it boring very soon if I have to look up words in alphabetical order :). It's something like browsing a dictionary :D

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to peruse [*MathWords*](http://www.mathwords.com/) and [*Math World*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/).

There is also a handy [*Math Notation*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/Notation.html) on Math World.

I would also recommend visiting your closest college library and looking through books and math dictionaries.

Comment: Great references, Amzoti!

Comment: @amWhy: this is one we've discussed where a lovely formatted and organized online math dictionary and symbols would be so awesome to have. Hmmm?

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is what I would do if I where in your situation. I would go to wikipedia in my language and look for the stuff I want to learn in the other language. Once I got to the page in my language I would click the button on the left that takes you to the english part. ( I recommend this if you allready know what you want to translate)

Something else you can do is pick up a book in english on precalculus. A book that contains a lot of materials and is easy to read (but not very proofy) is Stewart's precalculus. If you read that one you will know most of the definitions.

If you want a free source that gives definitions and provides intuition (but again isn't very proofy) I recommend you take a look at Khan Academy. This can also help you in english in general because Salman Khan speaks in english.

https://www.youtube.com/user/khanacademy/videos?view=1&flow=grid